# Socket.io io is not defined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code index.html file. I have already install socket.io package on NPM.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

I get the following error:

[image]

UPDATE: Using the CDN link and now I get the following errors on client console.

[image]

Comment: The file socket.io.js wasn't found. Either download it from somewhere and make sure it is in the right directory or GET it from a CDN instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many reasons for this. The most common one I find is how you initially declare Socket.io.

A correct setup would look like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

The other answer I noticed which said to use the CDN version of the file is an incorrect solution. Socket.io should generate it's own file for that if the server side is set up properly.

If you have any problems with this please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! It was http.listen instead of app.listen. Since I am passing http to the socket module.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [CDN version](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io();
</script>
```

**EDIT:** If you have those errors it means that the client-side `socket.io` is correctly plugged-in and you now have some kind of problem on the server-side part of it. If your `socket.io` server is running on port 8000 for example, try running the connection like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated the original question with update.